# Using excel vba, how to write a formula in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, formula

In Excel, A1 is equal to `=B1/ BDP(C11&”Corp”, “ds036”)`
Which `BDP(Corp, ds036)` is a function and parameters from Bloomberg.

How to use Excel VBA for this formula?

I was trying different ways in VBA to solve my point. One of them is like the line below,

```
Cells(1,1)=“B1/ BDP(C11&”Corp”, “ds036”)”
```

An other way I tried, to simplify,

```
For i=1 to10
    Cells(i,1)=“Cells(i,2)/ BDP(cells(i,3)&”Corp”, “ds036”)”
Next
```

Also, if it can access directly to BDP function. That will be perfect!

Comment: Are you trying to write the formula into the cell or access the BDP function from VBA to write the response into A1?

Comment: If it can access directly to BDP function. That will be perfect!

Comment: fix those smartquotes, they'll cause problem in Excel

Comment: For direct access to the BDP function, see this existing answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871743/bloomberg-data-why-doesnt-application-worksheetfunction-bdh-work). You can use `Application.Evaluate` to execute your BDP function, or work with the Bloomberg add-in to directly call the functions natively in VBA. If you use `Application.Evaluate`, be sure to fix your issues with quotation marks as identified by other commenters.

Comment: I’m still confused about the second way I used. How to apply cells(i,2) in a looping of my question instead of using B1 and C11?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
Cells(1,1).Formula = "=B1/ BDP(C11&""Corp"", ""ds036"")"
```

**Note:**

1. I used a different flavor of double quote
2. I doubled-up on the double quotes

Comment: Thank you! But one more question, How to apply cells(i,2) in a looping of my question instead of using B1 and C11?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
Range("A1:A10").Formula = "=B1/BDP(C3&""Corp"",""ds036"")"
```

If you assign a formula to a multi-cell range, I think Excel will automatically adjust relative cell references for subsequent rows/columns - similar to CTRL+D or dragging down.

This means you don't need to loop through each row and re-construct the formula string for each loop iteration.